# How to split text files by number of rows that corresponds to another set of files?

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, wc

Cut a file into several files according to numbers in a list:

```
$ wc -l all.txt
    8500   all.txt

$ wc -l STS.*.txt  
   2000 STS.input.answers-forums.txt
   1500 STS.input.answers-students.txt
   2000 STS.input.belief.txt
   1500 STS.input.headlines.txt
   1500 STS.input.images.txt
```

**How do I split my `all.txt` into the no. of lines of the `STS.*.txt` and then save them to the respective `STS.output.*.txt`?**

I've been doing it manually as such:

```
$ sed '1,2000!d' all.txt > STS.output.answers-forums.txt
$ sed '2001,3500!d' all.txt > STS.output.answers-students.txt
$ sed '3501,5500!d' all.txt > STS.output.belief.txt
$ sed '5501,7000!d' all.txt > STS.output.headlines.txt
$ sed '7001,8500!d' all.txt > STS.output.images.txt
```

The `all.txt` input would look something like this:

```
$ head all.txt
2.3059
2.2371
2.1277
2.1261
2.0576
2.0141
2.0206
2.0397
1.9467
1.8518
```

Or sometimes `all.txt` looks like this:

```
$ head all.txt
2.3059  92.123
2.2371  1.123
2.1277  0.12452
2.1261123   213
2.0576  100
2.0141  0
2.02062 1
2.03972 34.123
1.9467  9.23
1.8518  9123.1
```

As for the STS.*.txt, they are just plain text lines, e.g.:

```
$ head STS.output.answers-forums.txt
The problem likely will mean corrective changes before the shuttle fleet starts flying again.   He said the problem needs to be corrected before the space shuttle fleet is cleared to fly again.
The technology-laced Nasdaq Composite Index .IXIC inched down 1 point, or 0.11 percent, to 1,650.   The broad Standard & Poor's 500 Index .SPX inched up 3 points, or 0.32 percent, to 970.
"It's a huge black eye," said publisher Arthur Ochs Sulzberger Jr., whose family has controlled the paper since 1896.   "It's a huge black eye," Arthur Sulzberger, the newspaper's publisher, said of the scandal.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wish you'd posted some sample input for splitting an input file of, say, 10 lines into output files of say, 2, 3, and 5 lines instead of 8500 lines into.... as that would have given us something to test a solution against. Oh well, this might work but is untested of course:

```
awk '
ARGIND < (ARGC-1) { outfile[NR] = gensub(/input/,"output","",FILENAME); next }
{ print > outfile[FNR] }
' STS.input.* all.txt
```

The above used GNU awk for ARGIND and gensub().

It just creates an array that maps each line number across all "input" files to the name of the "output" file that that same line number of "all.txt" should be written to.

Any time you write a loop in shell just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach. The guys who created shell also created awk for shell to call to manipulate text so just do that.

Comment: Perhaps I'm just being slow but I think this answer could benefit from some explanation. Using a loop might not be the fastest approach but I think the resulting code is a lot more self-documenting.

Comment: I added a comment. Obviously there's about a dozen other possible solutions using awk so if that's not a desirable one, some other awk solution can still be used in preference to a shell loop.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest writing a loop:

```
for file in answers-forums answers-students belief headlines images; do
    lines=$(wc -l < "STS.input.$file.txt")
    sed "$(( total + 1 )),$(( total + lines ))!d" all.txt > "STS.output.$file.txt"
    (( total += lines ))
done
```

`total` keeps a track of how many lines have been read so far. The sed command extracts the lines from `total + 1` to `total + lines`, writing them to the corresponding output file.